# Characters Limitation To Store in Cosmos Graph

Tags: node.js, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

The problem is when I wanna store text which is in Persian/Arabic into the Cosmos Graph through a gremlin query in node js, It is failed:

```
 GremlinDriver.execute("g.V(id).out('includes')
                        .hasLabel('play')
                        .property('test', field_value)", 
                       { id: '123456', field_value: field_value })
```

If the `field_value` is in Persian Language like ("تست") I will get `Gremlin Query Parse Error`.
So, the question is *How can I resolve this issue in gremlin library?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is a limitation of C# gremlin driver. One trick which comes to my mind is using `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` likes the following:

```
GremlinDriver.execute("g.V(id).out('includes')
                        .hasLabel('play')
                        .property('test', field_value)", 
                       { id: '123456', field_value: encodeURIComponent(field_value) })
```

However, as I mentioned, there is this limitation in node-js gremlin driver.